# What is the name of this SAT test concept?

Tags: school

I’m looking for the academic name, or examples of pattern finding that is like

Tree/apple is to vine/(tomato)

There are other examples that probably illustrate different thought domains;

is this a concept that has a name?

Answer (score 19):

That is called an analogy. They were removed from the test in [2005](https://blog.prepscholar.com/sat-analogies-and-comparisons-why-removed-what-replaced-them).

Comment: I usually see them worded as "tree is to apple, as vine is to (tomato)" ... which would make it a **simile** instead of a metaphor (since the comparison is made using the word 'like' or 'as').

Comment: @ruakh: Ah, that makes more sense.